# Store return size * nmemb into a variable c++

Tags: c++, variables, return

How would I go about storing the `return size * nmemb`? I've tried `std::string verycool = size * nmemb;`

```cpp
static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the same type that `size` and `nmemb` themselves are using:

```cpp
static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    size_t numBytes = size * nmemb;
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, numBytes);
    return numBytes;
}
```

If, on the other hand, you want to access the value *after* `WriteCallback()` exits, just use the [`string::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) method for that, eg:

```cpp
std::string s;
functionThatSetsUserP(&s);
functionThatWrites(&WriteCallback);
size_t size = s.size();
```